# Android - Facebook status update

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using EasyFacebookAndroid SDK to update user's stats at Facebook.
I tested the method `setStatus(String message)` form GraphApi class to post a simple message and worked well.
However, I would like to share a link and I think this is the proper method:

```
setStatus(String message, String urlPicture, String actionsUrl, String actionsName)
```

What does "actionUrl" and "actionsName" mean?

Comment: I don't want to be mean, but the API Reference is kinda messy. Indeed, what do actionUrl and actionsName mean?